# Directory contents for maven project with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-eclipse-plugin

We have a multi-module maven project which has configuration for findbugs & checkstyle to run with maven builds. I want this configuration to be in sync with eclipse without having to commit IDE specific files like `.project`, `.settings`, `.checkstyle` etc in SCM.

Earlier I used to configure `maven-eclipse-plugin` with required `projectNature` and `buildCommand` and just ask the developers in team to run the `mvn eclipse:eclipse` goal to generate the ide specific files and then import it in eclipse as a Java project or as Maven project (either worked).

Now I see that `maven-eclipse-plugin` is outdated and must not be used. Importing maven projects in eclipse with only POM file having plugin configuration doesn't generate files like `.checkstyle` or findbugs config file in `.settings` folder.

How do I generate eclipse IDE specific files with only required configuration mentioned in POM? If a generic solution is available which could support other IDEs like IntelliJ also, I would prefer that but primarily I would like to solve the issue for eclipse.